# How to erase p:output value by JS

Tags: javascript, java, jsf

I got such kind of problem - I am trying to hide err message on jsf page when user clearing the related field by jsf function but it doesnt works

This is the snippet from my jsf page where i call jsf function

```
<div class="item">
<p:outputLabel for="phone" value="#{msgs['customerForm.phone']}"/>
<p:inputText id="phone" value="#{customerBean.customer.mobileNum}"
placeholder="380*********"required="true" requiredMessage="#{msgs['Error.phone.mandatory']}"
validatorMessage="#{msgs['Error.phone.wrongFormat']}">
<p:ajax event="keyup" oncomplete="hideCustomerErrMsg('phone')"/>
<f:validateRegex pattern="^380[\d]{9}$"/>
<f:ajax update="login"/>
<p:ajax event="change" update="login"/>
</p:inputText><p:message id="m_phone" for="phone" display="text"/>
</div>
```

this is snippet from my jsf page - the item i want to hide when user clear field dynamically

```
<div class="errorMessages">
<h:outputText id="f_phone" value="#{msgs['Error.phone.duplicate']}" rendered="#{customerBean.mobileDuplicate}"
styleClass="ui-message-error"/>
 <p:spacer width="20"/>
 </div>
```

this my js function

```
function hideCustomerErrMsg(variable) {
    var inputField, msg, span;
    inputField =document.getElementById("createEditCustomerForm:accordion:" + variable);
    msg = document.getElementById("createEditCustomerForm:accordion:m_" + variable);
    span = document.getElementById("createEditCustomerForm:f_" + variable).getElementsByTagName("span");
    if (inputField.value === "" && msg.hasChildNodes()) {
        msg.innerHTML = "";
        span.innerHTML ="";
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check - 
1. Open F12 developer tools and debug whether your function is calling or not when user clears the field
2. Just double check whether the ids you've given exist on the current dom or not. 
3. **getElementsByTagName** returns a collection of all matching elements. you've to iterate through them and for each and every element do innerHtml='';

```
 for(var key in span)
    {
        if(span[key])
     span[key].innerHTML='';
    }
```

Comment: What if I just wil use span = document.getElementById("createEditCustomerForm:f_" + variable)

Comment: is it possible? becouse span.innerHTML =""; doesnt work(

Comment: it should work fine. Could you please just add some test alerts and check so that we can know whether the actual if condition is being executed on not.

Comment: function hideCustomerErrMsg(variable, label) {
    var inputField, msg, err, d;
    inputField = document.getElementById("createEditCustomerForm:accordion:" + variable);
    msg = document.getElementById("createEditCustomerForm:accordion:m_" + variable);
    err = document.getElementById("createEditCustomerForm:accordion:" + label);
    d = document.getElementById("createEditCustomerForm:f_" + variable)
    if (inputField.value === "" && msg.hasChildNodes()) {
        d.innerHTML= ""
        msg.innerHTML = "";
    }}